# How can i get my south migrations to work?

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I am having trouble having south to work with my django project, i have followed the south documentation on converting apps to south and also looked here ([Why don't my south migrations work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840102/how-come-my-south-migrations-doesnt-work-for-django)) but all in vain.

After adding south to `INSTALLED_APPS` and run `syncdb`,

```
Synced:
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > smartmin
 > nsms.console
 > django_extensions
 > pagination
 > restaurant_detail
 > live
 > debug_toolbar
 > orders
 > django.contrib.admindocs

Not synced (use migrations):
 - django.contrib.auth
 - django.contrib.contenttypes
 - django.contrib.sessions
 - django.contrib.sites
 - guardian
 - south
 - django_quickblocks
 - rapidsms
 - rapidsms_httprouter
 - sorl.thumbnail
 - djangoratings
 - agon_ratings
 - django.contrib.admin
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

at this point i execute this command,`python manage.py migrate`, this gives error `django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "south_migrationhistory" does not exist
LINE 1: ...gration", "south_migrationhistory"."applied" FROM "south_mig...`

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried syncdb --migrate

Comment: @Charl it returns the same error

Comment: Is south in your installed apps?

Comment: yes it is @krak3n, if it wasn't i would be getting a different error..

Answer (score 14):

If this is your first migration or you just want to start over:

1. Drop and create your current database
2. Remove your migrations directory: `rm -Rf your_app/migrations/`
3. Sync and migrate in just one command: `python manage.py syncdb --migrate`

Next migrations would need:

1. `python manage.py schemamigration your_app --auto`
2. `python manage.py migrate your_app`

That works for me :)

Comment: note: you might need to delete migrations folders in other directories, like `site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations`

Answer (score 4):

This all came about because south in my `site_packages` had a migrations directory already, which i didn't know was there.When i got rid of the directory everything worked just fine.
Apologoies the stackoverflow folks that toiled to solve a problem that was caused due to my absent mindedness.

Comment: that was a life saver, that folder is not even deleted when you do pip uninstall south :)

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be created by following well meaning advice: if you tried `python manage.py schemamigration south --initial` at any point in your debugging attempts, you'll create a 'migrations' folder in your site-packages in the South app itself. Unfortunately, the existence of a `migrations` folder is how South determines if it should skip an app when performing its altered syncdb process. Including if that app... is South.

When you drop your database to try and debug from scratch, South's modified syncdb will skip creating the `south_migrationhistory` table, assuming that the migrations folder will know better, and the migrations table requires the `south_migrationhistory` table to work.

To solve the issue:

1. Go into your site packages and delete the `migrations/` folder in the south app.
2. Run `python ./manage.py syncdb` one last time

Uninstalling/reinstalling South via pip won't actually cut it, as it'll leave the offending folder untouched.

Alternately, [Marius Grigaitis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626979/problems-installing-south-with-django-south-migrationhistory-tables-do-not-get) proposed a workaround to the same error, although it was attributed at the time to a south bug.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first migrate south itself to create south tables, then you can migrate your other applications:

```
# python manage.py migrate south
# python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the migrations' tables are not being created in your database. It's a little bit odd by maybe this will work:

```
python manage.py schemamigration south --initial
python manage.py migrate south
```

and then continue with the other migrations.

Comment: If you don't have your south tables, you want to add south tables to your non-existing south tables ?

Comment: @Liarez I really appreciate your feedback but as you can see, the answer of this questions was kind of _odd_ and it is almost one year old. When I answered this I was just taking a hunch (as you can see, there were others too). How do you expect me to remind what I was thinking in that moment? Anyways, feel free to downvote :)

Comment: I just had that problem, and I saw many people repeating things like your answer, and it doesn't have any sense if south is not working trying to migrate to himself, thats why the downvote, because the answer doesn't help at all

Comment: @Liarez fair enough. Good to know you found the answer to your problem.